# facebook real time subscriptions api

Tags: facebook, real-time, subscriptions

How do you subscribe to the real time API to user photos changes in order to get the likes and comments of user uploaded photos when they are liked and commented? Are there any necessary app settings or specific graph api calls that need to be made?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.4

Keep in mind that you can only receive `user` updates if the user has given your application the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I've subscribed to user photos; the permission required would be user_photos. Does this give me a notification when a user photo is liked or commented?

Comment: why not just try it?

Comment: Really? I tried it and I'm not receiving anything when a like or comment is issued, hence the question if this is the proper way to do this? If you know the answer post it, otherwise please do not interfere with questions if you have nothing better to do

Comment: Your question is quite very broad. @luschn is right. If you already tried something, wrote code etc. you should put this in your question. StackOverflow is not a programming service. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And being rude will not get your problem solve.

Comment: The question is not broad at all, that is the smallest task it is broken into and can be obtained, subscribing for user photos to get likes and comments by the real time subscriptions API; since you pointed out the documentation you probably know that nowhere in there says anything helpful or specific regarding this exact issue: likes and comments

Comment: you did not post any code or anything you have tried. how should we know if you have tried on your own already? ;) - so tobis answer is actually the best you can get with that amount of detail in your question. i mean, we don´t even know what programming language you are using, it´s a very broad question.

Comment: @luschn I guess it's not worth to invest any further effort.